# Rendering a triangular face in 3d space

Tags: java, image, 3d, camera, projection

Let's say I have a triangular face in 3d space, and I have the 3d coordinates of each vertex of this triangle, and would also have other information about the triangle(angles, lengths of sides, etc.). In Java, if I have the viewing screen and its information, how can I draw that plane, without using libraries like LWJGL, to that image, assuming I can properly project, accounting for perspective, any 3d point to that 2d image.

Would the best course of action just be to run a loop that draws each point on the plain to a point on the image(i.e. setting the corresponding pixel), which will most likely set the same pixel multiple times? If I'd do this, what would be the best way to identify each point in an oblique triangle, or a triangle that doesn't line up nicely with the axes?

tl;dr: I have a triangular face in 3d space, a "camera" looking at the face, and an image in which I can set each pixel. Using no GL libraries, what's the best way to project and draw that face onto the image?

Comment: Creation of 3d graphics libraries & methods is very complicated. I can direct you by saying start off by creating a method that takes two 3d points and drawing a line between them and showing it in a 2d screen with perspective after that things become some what simpler. [OGRE](http://www.ogre3d.org/download/source) is an open source 3D engine, take a look at that for ideas.

Answer (score 0):

**Projection** :

won't detail as you seems to know it

**Drawing a line**

you can look at Bresenham algorithm if you wanna start with the basics
(hardwared in recent graphics card)

**Filling**

you can fill between left and right borders of the triangle while you use Bresenham on both (you could use a floodfill algorithm starting ... i don't know, maybe at the projection of the center of the triangle)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think of using a flood-fill. Quick question though, if I use a flood-fill, is there a way to produce something other than a solid color area? Say I wanted the face to display a lighting, or mapped a bitmap to it, would you still recommend using something akin to a flood fill, or might "rendering" each point in the triangle(either skipping already rendered pixels on screen or overriding them) be preferrable?

Comment: I really don't get how you want to process "each point" in a triangle. 
Whatever, if you get how bresenham works, you can create an new increment, using any property that you want (for example color) and add this increment to the algorithm. This should give you the "vertical" interpolation as you are filling from top to bottom.
For the "horizontal" interpolation, when you have the left pixel, left pixel color, right pixel, and right pixel color, you have all you need

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to check out the g.fillPolygon() function for Java. It allows you to draw polygons with as many sides as possible and theres also g.drawPolygon() if you don't want it solid. Then you can just do some simple maths for the points. Such as each point is basically it's x and y except if the polygon is further away the points move closer to the center of the polygon and if the polygon is closer they move further away from the center of the polygon.

A second idea could be using some sort of array to store pixels and then researching line drawing algorithms and drawing lines then putting all the line data in another array and using some sort of flood-fill. Then whilst it's in that array you could try and do some weird stuff to the pixels if you wanted textures or something.